# how to get value of cell of sheet1 and add it with value of sheet2 in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have two separate excel sheets `Book 1` and `Book 2`. I want to get value of `Total sales` which is in `Book 1` and add it in `Book 2` grand total column. I have use `Connections` in `Data` and add a `Workbook Connection` of `Book 1`, now how can i get the data as i have mentioned above? I have searched a lot but unable to find the solution.

Comment: You are over-complicating the matter. Open the two workbooks side-by-side then type `=` in *grand total* and click on the other workbook's *Total sales* cell.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

*You probably didn't find a solution because as long as almost any Excel/VBA code would have the answer of your question, there wouldn't be any specific question on this matter.*

I assume your `Total Sales` column is `B Column` in `Sheet1` of `Book1` starts at `1st row`which is `B1`

Now if you copy this below code to first cell of your `Grand Total` column in `Book2` you will see your *desired* outcome.

```
='[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B1
```

**And the only thing you need to do from this point is dragging your selection below to extend this series.**

*If any of my guesses above are not correct, change those parts on the formula.*

For instance: If your Excel file is in *Binary format*, then change *.xlsx* with **.xlsb** and if your spread sheet name is `MyLovelySheet` instead of *Sheet1*, and your *Total Sales* column is in **T** column, then you should edit the formula as below:

```
='[Book1.xlsb]MyLovelySheet'!$T1
```